# How to insert multiple file upload into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, rows

I have coded this far but the only issue i have is that i can't save multiple rows for the same user id when the user uploads several pictures. the code works perfectly fine, I mean the multiple files gets inserted into the file system folder/root directory but the reference in the database doesn't quit work. It only inserts the first file uploaded image not the the second file upload.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
 if(isset($_POST['go'])) {
     if(isset($_FILES['file_array'])){
        $errors= array();
        foreach($_FILES['file_array']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ) {
            $user = $_SESSION['user_id'];
            $file_name = $key.$_FILES['file_array']['name'][$key];
            $file_size =$_FILES['file_array']['size'][$key];
            $file_tmp =$_FILES['file_array']['tmp_name'][$key];
            $file_type=$_FILES['file_array']['type'][$key];
        }
        $extensions = array("jpeg","jpg","png");     
        $file_ext=explode('.',$_FILES['file_array']['name'][$key]);
        $file_ext=end($file_ext);  
        $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['file_array']['name'][$key])));  
        if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions ) === false) {
            $errors[]="extension not allowed";
        }  
        if($_FILES['file_array']['size'][$key] > 2097152) {
            $errors[]='File size must be less tham 2 MB';
        }
        $query = array();
        $myarray = '';
        if(is_array($query)) {
            foreach ($query as $row) {
                $query[] = '('.$row['ID'].',"'.$row['FILE_NAME'].'", "'.$row['FILE_TYPE'].'", "'.$row['FILE_SIZE'].'")';        
            }
        }
        $dir = "users_data/profile/users_posted_data/";

        if(empty($errors)==true) {
            if(is_dir($dir)==false){
                mkdir("$dir/", 0700);
            } 
            if(is_dir("$dir/".$file_name)==false) {
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$dir/".$file_name);
            } else {
                $new_dir="$dir/".$file_name.time();
                rename($file_tmp, "$dir/".$file_name);
            }
            $query_run = mysqli_query($mysqli, 'INSERT INTO table (ID, FILE_NAME,FILE_SIZE, FILE_TYPE) VALUES '.implode(',', $query));
        } else {
            print_r($errors);
        }

        if(empty($error)) {
            echo "Success";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `foreach ($query as $row)` isn't iterating as 3 lines above you're emptying it with `$query = array();` Also, potential endless loop when adding to `$query` on each iteration of foreach? I think you confused `$query` and `$myarray`.

Comment: so should I remove the $query = array(); or should I put in the filed varialbes in it? thanks.

Comment: well, i get foreach invalid argument when I put in $myarray as $row.

Comment: You messed brackets earlier, no array for SQL query is being built as you loop through files earlier, you reassign same variables, it's a mess.

Comment: @DeDee so what do you suggest me to do? can you please explain a little further? thanks.

Comment: A bit of sensible code formatting may help you see whats actually going on

Comment: @koroush quote:"_well, i get foreach invalid argument when I put in $myarray as $row._". Of course, it's a string type, this shows you have no idea about the code you have there.

Comment: @DeDee hahahaa I am a new programmer trying to learn. What do you expect? so can you help me out instead of humiliating me please :D

Comment: See @RiggsFolly 's last comment on his answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to iterate over an empty array. Not sure what you were actually trying to do but this will do nothing.

```
   $query = array();    // init array
   $myarray = '';
   if(is_array($query)) {   // test that its an array which it obviously is see 2 lines previous
       foreach ($query as $row) {    // iterate over empty array
           // add to the array we are **not** iterating over
           $query[] = '('.$row['ID'].',"'.$row['FILE_NAME'].'", "'.$row['FILE_TYPE'].'", "'.$row['FILE_SIZE'].'")';        
       }
   }
```

Comment: this looks like the same thing the OP was doing?

Comment: @nomistic It is, I was just informing him that iterating over an empty array was a waste of time. What else can one do with this question. The OP has obviously had a brain fart and I have no idea what he was trying to do so I cannot even point him in the right direction

Comment: I think he is just trying to feed an array of the uploaded files into his database

Comment: Of course he is, but he is not even close. He has not once bothered to check '$_FILES['file_array']['error']` just in case stuff went wrong. To fix it would involve a fairly serious refactor of the code. Suggest OP goes back to basics and starts again